# Collect and pass along abitrary parameters in Puppet

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to (a) accept arbitrary arguments to a class or resource definition and then (b) pass those arguments on to another class or resource definition?

I often find that what I am writing is a thin wrapper over a native
type or over a third-party module.  For example:

```
define myconfigfile {
  file { "/path/to/$name":
    owner => lars,
    group => lars,
    ...
  }
}
```

That is, `myconfigfile` is effectively shorthand for a set of file
resources with a known prefix.  I would actually like `myconfigfile`
to accept the same parameters as the `file` resource type (such as
`content`, `source`, etc), but I would like to avoid:

```
define myconfigfile (
  $content = undef,
  $source = undef
) {
  ...
}
```

This works okay when there are only one or two parameters, but it
becomes unmanageable if I am trying to wrap a parameterized class with
lots of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use a [hash](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#hashes) to pass in an arbitrary list of parameters.

Another, and perhaps better option would be to make use of the [Ruby DSL](http://www.puppetlabs.com/blog/ruby-dsl/) which allows you to use Ruby instead of the Puppet language.

There are a variety of [examples](https://github.com/bobsh/puppet-rubydsl-examples) available as well.

Essentially, you would pass in the hashmap then use Ruby's iteration/looping (the ruby [hash object](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/hashes.htm) has a .each method)  to extract the key-value pairs from the hash.

The Ruby DSL became available in 2.6.x.

Comment: And then what?  I've used hash parameters for templates in the past, but I'm not sure how to best make use of them for the situation described in my question.

Comment: You'd have to know what was passed in, so it would be somewhat difficult. It's a shame that puppet doesn't have better iteration in it's language, outside of templates.

Comment: Updated the answer, so it actually provides an solution now.

Comment: The Ruby DSL has been deprecated.